# Dockerized Flask App / Crashing on Heroku while locally running image works fine

Tags: python, docker, flask, heroku

When building and running the docker image locally the flask app starts successfully and everything works as expected.

However when deployed to ***Heroku*** the app crashes and exists right away.

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM python:3.9.4

ADD . /blockchain-py

WORKDIR /blockchain-py

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]

CMD ["server.py"]
```

***heroku.yml***

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
```

I have also tried adding the ***Procfile*** (to no avail)

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:${PORT} wsgi server:app --log-file=-
```

Error Message from heroku logs:

```
2021-05-27T08:01:39.206659+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-27T08:01:55.599292+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python3`
2021-05-27T08:01:58.310259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-05-27T08:01:58.390600+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-27T08:01:58.409515+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-27T08:02:18.130426+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python3`
2021-05-27T08:02:21.371471+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-05-27T08:02:21.466571+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-05-27T08:02:23.139469+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=blockchain-server-py.herokuapp.com request_id=69be5144-0665-4bc6-8616-e15b34ea370f fwd="95.91.235.135" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-05-27T08:02:23.845517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=blockchain-server-py.herokuapp.com request_id=7262f8a8-264a-47cb-9cfa-f67d27ee4470 fwd="95.91.235.135" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

***server.py***

```
import os
from typing import Dict, Union
from server.response import Response
from blockchain import *
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS
from server.responseHelpers import get_message, get_missing_fields, get_serializable_block, get_serializable_transaction, has_all_required_fields, jsonify_chain
from server.models.statusCodes import HttpStatusCodes
from server.requestHelpers import get_param
from core.blockchainFactory import BlockchainFileStorageFactory

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

blockchain = Blockchain(BlockchainFileStorageFactory)

host = '0.0.0.0'
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))


@app.route('/', methods=[HttpStatusCodes.GET])
def get_ui():
    return send_from_directory('ui/templates', 'node.html')


# ... some more routes 

print('Starting Server...')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host, port, debug=True)
```

Comment: can you shre your `server.py` file data?

Comment: added the server.py file (shortened, did not include all route definitions)

Comment: shouldn't `methods=[HttpStatusCodes.GET]` be `methods=[GET]` ?

Comment: no, it works fine, I created my own wrapper around status codes. ```class HttpStatusCodes(str, Enum):
    GET = 'GET'
    POST = 'POST'
    PUT = 'PUT'
```

Comment: check how to invoke python in heroku server, ie either it is invoke with `python` or `python3`

Comment: I tried both, python3 and python. same error occurs.

Comment: I'm having the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67756545/heroku-missing-required-flag-a-app-error-after-succesfully-running-heroku-c , if you manage to solve the problem please let me know! Also I tried to add the library gunicorn to my requirements without success :(

Comment: Try removing the EXPOSE 5000 from the Dockerfile, also the answer provided in my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67756545/heroku-missing-required-flag-a-app-error-after-succesfully-running-heroku-c might be useful (I solved my problem which I believe is similar to yours)

Comment: thanks, but did not solve the problem. @antonioACR1 do you have a repo I can check out? What about your heroku.yml?

Answer (score 0):

Use upper case when accessing env variables (`PORT`)

```
port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
```

Comment: thanks, good point. But does not resolve the issue.